# Post with Robospice and okHttp

Tags: post, okhttp, robospice

I perform a POST using Robospice and okHttp :

```
public String loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
    uriBuilder = Uri.parse(url).buildUpon();
    uri = new URI(uriBuilder.build().toString());
    tmp = "user=" + user + "&password=" + pwd
    HttpURLConnection connect = new OkUrlFactory(client).open(uri.toURL());
    // Send post request
    connect.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connect.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(tmp);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    // Read the response
    in = connect.getInputStream();
}
```

Is there a better way to send a post (*with Robospice/okHttp*) ?

**NB** : my code is working fine, just want to know if it's correct or  not...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if I want to use the okHttp POST like that :

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://api.github.com/markdown/raw")
            .post(RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN, parameters))
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

    System.out.println(response.body().string());
```

with Robospice, RequestBody and newCall and isSuccessful cannot be resolved !

Do I have a solution to use okHttp post WITH Robospice ? (I know how to make a GET, but not a POST...)

Comment: SORRY !!! I have added the librairy in my graddle (compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'), and now it's OK

Comment: It's ok but as I added the okHttp library, the Robospice GET is not working anymore... So I'm still with my problem...

Comment: Any solution for the above

Comment: Yes, don't use Robospice anymore... Use RXJava instead

Comment: I have implemented RXJava with retrofit. But when I hit my first call it get succeeded. While hitting second call, it throws an error close the previous response body. How can I close the previous repsponse body